# Dynamic event to handle download file async completed, and download async progress changed

Tags: c#, .net

im trying to create a tumblr image downloader,
my problem is when i need to download 100 image in one time.
i'm searching in google that i cant download 100 image in one time with one object webclient
so i will create new webclient every downloading.
the problem is eventhandler for downloadasyncCompleted and download progresschanged is always same.
how can i resolve this?

maybe my question is wrong
but what i need is :
1. download multiple file in one time
2. control the progresschanged event with dynamically created progressbar (progressbar total is same with how much the picture will download)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make 30 threads each with their own web client and then use a ConcurrentQueue of string. Then push all the uri's only the queue then start all the threads they can have a while(trydequque()) and then each thread can dl. 30 threads works pretty good and a quad core pc. You can use download no need to use async this way.

```
ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

        queue.Enqueue("http://link.jpg");

        for (var x = 0; x < 30; x++)
        {
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    //create webclient here
                    string uri;
                    while(queue.TryDequeue(out uri))
                    {
                        //download here
                    }
                })).Start();
        }
```

Comment: if i not use async my software will freeze(not responding)

Comment: If you try and call the webclient in your UI thread then yes. However if you create threads your ui will not freeze.

Comment: can i create webclient and progressbar together? and set the progresschanged event to every progress bar i created? like first loop create progressbar1 and add progresschanged event to progressbar1, second loop create progressbar2 and the progresschanged with same event with progressbar1?

Comment: You would need a more complex object and would need to download the image as a stream into a buffer an call a method in the form using Invoke. To update the progress bar.

Comment: im curious how this software created http://i.imgur.com/P1gaOc5.png, when i see the source in reflector. this software using threading, enqueue, dequeue and looping like your answer, than using invoke at webClient ProgressChanged event to change the visibility of progressbar when progressbar.value at 100

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're calling the "DownloadFileAsync" function 100 times in a loop, then getting back your results slowly in a messy order. I'd recommend maintaining a list of URIs to download and storing an index of what you're up to. In your event handler for download finished, start the download of the next object. Download them one at a time.

It wont be "downloading all the files at the same time' but that's functionally impossible anyway, you shouldn't lose significant download performance by doing them one at a time.

To recap:

- Establish your list of URI's to download (the addresses)
- Keep a track of the index in that list of the URI that's currently downloading
- In the download completed event, increment that index and start the download for the next one if there's still more.

This way, whenever download completed gets fired, you know that the file that just finished downloading was the file behind the URI at [index] in your list of files to download.

This should also mean that you wont need to destroy and create a new WebClient for every request.

Comment: this software can download up to 100 image in one time http://i.imgur.com/P1gaOc5.png and it can control progresschanged event with dynamically created control

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DownloadFileAsync overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144197.aspx) that lets you pass a user token. That token will be presented in the `UserState` property of the `DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs` and `AsyncCompletedEventArgs`. So, if you have:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChangedHandler;
client.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadCompletedHandler;
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(urlToDownload), filename, urlToDownload);
// ...

void DownloadProgressChangedHandler(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string urlToDownload = (string)e.UserState;  // get the URL we're downloading from
    // do whatever
}

void DownloadCompletedHandler(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string urlToDownload = (string)e.UserState; // get the URL we're downloading from
    // whatever
}
```

Note that you can pass any data you like in that third parameter to `DownloadFileAsync`. If you want to pass multiple fields, then you'll need to create a class that has properties, or create a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the multiple fields. In either case, you'll still cast the `e.UserState` field to whatever type it actually is, and then access it.